# Swift syntax error in adding element to Array

Tags: swift

There are syntax error in it. New to Swift :(

```
var inputString: String = "Hello its question? </question> Oky its the answer"

let splitter: String = "</question>"
var splittedArray = [inputString .componentsSeparatedByString(splitter)]


var questionIndex = 0
var answerIndex = 0
var mQuestions = []
var mAnswers = []


for var index = 0; index < splittedArray.count; ++index {
if index % 2 == 0{
    // Question comes first
    splittedArray.append(mQuestions[questionIndex])
    questionIndex++
}else{
    // Answer comes second

 splittedArray.append(mAnswers[answerIndex])
    answerIndex++
   }
}
```

Error is:

> An Object is not convertable to String,

at this line of code.

```
splittedArray.append(mQuestions[questionIndex])
```

Comment: An Object or AnyObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed syntax errors, but that's not all:

- You can't inline Objective-C code as you're doing with `[inputString.components...]`
- You can't initialize an empty array without specifying its type
- You've got the object and the parameter reversed in your `appends`

---

Here's a quick rewrite addressing the above:

```
import Foundation

var inputString = "Hello its question? </question> Oky its the answer"

let splitter = "</question>"
var splittedArray = inputString.componentsSeparatedByString(splitter) as [String]

var mQuestions = [String]()
var mAnswers = [String]()

while splittedArray.count >= 2 {
    mQuestions.append(splittedArray.removeAtIndex(0))
    mAnswers.append(splittedArray.removeAtIndex(0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var splittedArray = [inputString .componentsSeparatedByString(splitter)]
```

Bit of an objective-c hangover here. With those square brackets, you're making this an array with an array inside it. That's going to make `splittedArray` have the wrong type, and the wrong contents.

Once this program compiles it will also crash, because you're then appending to `splittedArray` from an empty `mQuestions` array, using an out of bounds index.